# What does PIP stand for?

Tags: python

What does [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) stand for?
Does it stands for Python Package Installer?

No, I don't think so, it is `PPI`

Comment: What? // 15 char minimum

Comment: I want to know PIP abbreviation

Comment: Where did you see it? What is it related to? Do you have any clues? Did you do some research, like looking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip), at **Science and technology** > **Computing** ?

Comment: One Google Search would have given you [this WikiPedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) and [their Homepage](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Comment: guys, before downvoting or voting to close, please provide an authoritative reference that clearly states what's the official acronym definition if there's one. The links provided by John and @eyoung100 don't answer the question. (one may argue that the question has little to do with Unix or Linux though).

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer the question, but in all fairness, that is what Google Returns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PIP stands for **P**ip **I**nstalls **P**ython or **P**IP **I**nstalls **P**ackages

It is easily available if you just Google it. Click here to know [How to ask question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Attribution [here](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/pip&prev=search) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym#Notable_examples)

Comment: Please change the link to point to English page

Comment: I cannot find a English versdion of it, So I have translated via Google translater. Thanks  UUV

Comment: "pip installs packages" is more commonly found. [here wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym#Notable_examples)

Comment: It's another [recursive acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym).  An oxymoronic example: SNARA stands for "SNARA's Not A Recursive Acronym".  But it is.  You saw it here first ;)

Comment: > It is easily available if you just Google it

Hilariously, Google brought me here.

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html, pip stands for "preferred installer program".

Comment: @Dataman The docs you point to does not say pip is an acronym for  "preferred installer program," it's saying pip *is* the preferred installer program. It's the difference between saying Windows is a trash operating system versus "Windows is an acronym for 'Trash Operating System.'"